# How to use the ifsym package?

Tags: packages

I have added `\usepackage{ifsym}` in the front, and LaTeX cannot parse the command `\Letter`. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Try `\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}`.

Comment: I had the same problem, diddn't want to use Letter but it was classhing
seems ifsym clashes with marvosym, unload the latter and it fixed it

Answer (score 36):

By default the package only sets up the command `\textifsymbol` and a couple of font selection commonds, such as `\textifsym`, which will produce LCD type digits and certain chemistry related symbols.  To get the Letter icon you can write `\textifsymbol{0}`.  Of course that is not convenient.  In order to use the more meaningful command names, you need to load the package with one of its options:

- `clock` - provides `\showclock` and different clock symbols
- `weather` - weather symbols `\Sun`, `\Rain`,...
- `misc` - includes the `\Letter` icon you are after
- `alpine` - map symbols for alpine regions e.g. `\Hut`, `\Summit`,...
- `geometry` - circles, squares, diamonds,...
- `electronic` - digital signals

So as cgnieder says `\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}` will provide the `\Letter` command.

Answer (score 7):

And if you want to add more than one you have to write, for example:

```
\usepackage[misc,clock,geometry]{ifsym}
```

in the `[ ]` include the sub-packages that you want...
(You have the options above...:-) )