# Issue with \Sun symbol in ifsym package

Tags: symbols, packages

I have installed the `ifsym` package and added the following line to my .tex file:

```
\usepackage{ifsym}
```

When I try printing the sun symbol through `\Sun` I get this error:

> ! Undefined control sequence. l.226
>   Testing \Sun

What am I missing?

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX, you could be missing one of many things, or none at all... It's hard to tell without a Minimal Working Example (MWE). Please add that so we can try and see what's up.

Comment: try `\usepackage[weather]{ifsym}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use the ifsym package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100424/how-to-use-the-ifsym-package)

Comment: `\usepackage[weather]{ifsym}` worked for me, thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Converting my comment into an answer]

You need to pass the appropriate option when loading the `ifsym` package to access the symbols. In your case, you need to pass the option `weather`, like so:

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[weather]{ifsym}

\begin{document}
    We are \Sun\ when the question has been answered.
\end{document}
```

[image: sunny]

Related answer provided by Andrew: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100578/117534